# How to remotely manage (with PhpMyAdmin) a MySQL RDS on a load-balanced AWS Elastic Beanstalk setup?

Tags: mysql, permissions, phpmyadmin, ssl, amazon-ec2

Although there are similar questions and topics, I can't find a solution that currently works.

I specifically wrote *remotely manage* because I'd like to use my home computer's PhpMyAdmin to directly connect to the RDS instance and keep its 'public accessibility' to private.

What I've done so far:

- installed PhpMyAdmin on my home computer (mac osx) and got it working
- added an inbound rule for the security group used by the RDS (rule: my.home.network's.ipv4/32, port 3306)
- configured my mac's phpmyadmin `conf.inc.php` according to [this](https://degreesofzero.com/article/manage-remote-mysql-servers-with-local-phpmyadmin.html) suggestion. I've never done SSH tunneling, but the idea seems safer than opening 3306 to the public. So I've set it up accordingly, but these are the PhpMyAdmin errors I get:

  - Cannot log in to the MySQL server
  - mysqli_real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
  - mysqli_real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=xxxx
  - mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away

Any ideas what I'm missing/doing wrong? Also, do I need to have MySQL at all installed on the mac? I assumed I didn't need it since I'd be using the remote one, but I've installed it anyway, and tried both with and without it. Same errors.

Thank you!

Comment: ssh forwarding can also forward unix sockets (specify path instead of port number). State your ssh tunnel and phpmyadmin configuration. Can you locally connect using `mysql` to the local side of your osx connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out. I was close. It turns out I was doing the SSH tunneling wrong, and that's because I had no idea what I was doing. So after a bit more research I realized that I needed to change the remote host to be the RDS, not the EC-2.

So I ended up running the `ssh` command like this:

`ssh -L 3306:my-rds-endpoint:3306 ec2-user@my-ec2-endpoint -i /path/to/aws-eb/key`

Or add `-fN` if you want to run it in the background:

`ssh -fNL 3306:my-rds-endpoint:3306 ec2-user@my-ec2-endpoint -i /path/to/aws-eb/key`

The `config.inc.php` ended up being configured like so:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';
```

So yeah, my issue was understanding the ssh command, and realizing that I needed to change it so it would **tunnel to the RDS endpoint through the EC2 instance**. Also, I had some weird issue with my mac's local MySQL still running in the background, so it wouldn't allow a new connection to the 3306 port. Once I ran `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown` PhpMyAdmin could finally connect to the RDS!